# T-SQL parsing XML giving blank value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have been through the numerous questions on this issue here and none of those resolutions seem to work. I have the following XML:

```
DECLARE @XML xml;
SELECT @XML ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hb:MedicalAidMessage xmlns:hb="bridge.co.za/mes" Version="6.0.0">
    <Claim>
        <Details>
            <LineItems>
                <LineItem>
                    <HBBatchNum>2414</HBBatchNum>
                </LineItem>
            </LineItems>
        </Details>
    </Claim>
</hb:MedicalAidMessage>';
```

and this code to parse it:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('bridge.co.za/mes' as ns)
SELECT
    ISNULL(T.N.value('HBBatchNum[1]', 'INT'), 0) AS BatchNo
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/Claim/Details/LineItems/LineItem[1]') AS T(N)
```

Which is returning a blank value instead of 2414.  In the live query the XML is stored in a table column.  I just cannot figure out why I am not getting the node value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly obvious... `Claim` is not the root element. So use one of the following:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('bridge.co.za/mes' AS ns)
SELECT ISNULL(T.N.value('HBBatchNum[1]', 'int'),0) AS BatchNo
FROM @XML.nodes('/ns:MedicalAidMessage/Claim/Details/LineItems/LineItem[1]') AS T(N)

-- WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('bridge.co.za/mes' AS ns)
SELECT ISNULL(T.N.value('HBBatchNum[1]', 'int'),0) AS BatchNo
FROM @XML.nodes('/*:MedicalAidMessage/Claim/Details/LineItems/LineItem[1]') AS T(N)
```

Comment: No namespace registration necessary when you use `/*/Claim/Details/LineItems/LineItem[1]`.

Comment: @Tomalak, using `*` when it's not absolutely necessary is a very bad idea, performance wise.

Comment: @RogerWolf No, it isn't, really. And it's definitely not in this case.

Comment: When running this in the live DDB I get the following error: Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: @marc perhaps your data is not stored as XML. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892059/msg-9402-level-16-state-1-line-9-xml-parsing-line-1-character-38-unable-to

Comment: You're right- whomever designed the dtaabase put the XML message into a varchar column...  Ah well, guess I'll just have to parse it as a string...