# Convert an XML UTF-8 encoded string to XML datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, utf-8

Converting an XML string using CAST( AS XML) works as expected in many scenarios, but fail with an error "illegal xml character" if the string contains accented chars.

This example fails with error "XML parsing: line 2, character 8, illegal xml character":

```
declare @Text VARCHAR(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>'

select CAST(@Text AS XML)
```

According to [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) all of them are legal XML chars, but replacing accented chars with an 'X' char will result in a sucessfull CAST:

```
declare @MessageText VARCHAR(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>nXveis porXm alocaXXo</ROOT>'

select CAST(@MessageText AS XML)
```

Result: `<ROOT>nXveis porXm alocaXXo</ROOT>`

Moreover, the same XML but UTF-16 encoded, inexplicably works:

```
declare @MessageText NVARCHAR(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>'

select CAST(@MessageText AS XML)
```

Result: `<ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>`

Are those chars illegal in UTF-8? Or there is a better way to convert into an XML datatype?

Comment: In the first example, you declared Text variable, but select MessageText. If replace the variable name, it works fine on my server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server strips any XML Declaration prolog internally for XML data type and uses UTF-16 encoding. Here is how to handle correctly your use case.

> SQL

```
-- Method #1
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'<ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>';
SELECT CAST(@Text AS XML);

-- Method #2
DECLARE @MessageText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>';

SELECT CAST(@MessageText AS XML);
```

Comment: Please, may you provide any reference about "SQL Server strips any XML Declaration prolog internally"? In that case this code should work but is not: `DECLARE @MessageText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ROOT>níveis porém alocação</ROOT>'; SELECT CAST(@MessageText AS XML);`

Comment: Here is a good link for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494856/sql-server-defining-an-xml-type-column-with-utf-8-encoding

Comment: Another good BOL link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/bb330962(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#xml-data-type

Comment: And one more, specially its Comments section: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Introducing-UTF-8-support-for-SQL-Server/ba-p/734928